# Graded rings and maximal ideals of a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a graded ring,$p$ a homogeneous prime ideal in $S$, and $S_{(p)}$ the subring of elements of degree 0 in the localization of $S$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $T$ consisting of homogeneous elements of $S$ not in $p.$

1. How do the elements of $S_{(p)}$ look like ? In the case $S$ denotes the polynomial ring in $n$ indeterminates, are these elements the constant polynomials ?
2. How one can determine the maximal ideal of $S_{(p)}$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The elements are quotients $f/g$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of same degree and $g$ is not contained in p.
2. The maximal ideal consists of quotiensts $f/g$ where $f$ is contained in $p$. All other elements are clearly invertible.

Comment: Thanks. What's the idea behind your answer 2. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: f/g is invertible if and only g/f is contained in the ring. This is the if and only f is not contained in the prime ideal by 1. Also note for a local ring i.e. a ring R with a maximal ideal m you can characterize the maximal ideal as the set of non invertible elements. This is because if m contained an invertible element it would generate the whole ring as an ideal. On the other hand each non invertible element generates a non trivial ideal and is hence contained in the maximal  ideal.

Comment: Thanks. Why the restriction of taking the complement of the prime ideal is relevant for the localisation?

Comment: Your explanation concerning the maximal ideal is very clear. Can you provide a similar explanation concerning the point 1., which is to say that only if both $f$ and $g$ are not in the prime ideal, $f/g$ will be invertible?